# No known conversion from a pointer type to a reference to pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I have a code that looks somewhat like this:

```
struct Ifoo: virtual public Ibar {  
...  
}  

struct foo : public Ifoo, public bar {  
...  
}
```

And a function that is declared like:

```
bool function(Ifoo *&ref);
```

And its called like:

```
foo *variable = new foo();
bool value = function(dynamic_cast<Ifoo*>(foo));
```

I get the following error:

```
_No known conversion between types Ifoo* and Ifoo*&_
```

**BUT**, if i do the following:

```
Ifoo *variable = new foo();  
bool value = function(foo);
```

Then it works! 
I really don't understand why. Could you give me a hand?

Comment: Are you sure this code is correct? You're creating a variable `variable` and trying to `dynamic_cast` the struct `foo`?

Comment: This makes no sense : `dynamic_cast<IFoo*>(foo)`, nor does `function(foo)`. `foo` is a **type**, not a variable. *Neither* of these code samples "work". Second, once you fix the code to properly reflect using `variable`, then `dynamic_cast<>` isn't giving you a modifiable reference; its just a value. That reference-parameter has to reference *something*. You're not giving it something with that cast (that the cast was even tried due to the error you're *not* showing,  which is the real X in this XY problem, should have been the first indicator something is wrong).

Comment: remove the dynamic_cast

Answer (score 1):

The result of the cast is a temporary.  You can't bind a temporary with a non-const lvalue reference.

Why are you passing the pointer by reference?  Does the function modify it?  What happens to type-safety if the function stores a pointer to a different subclass of `Ifoo`?

Answer (score 0):

A `foo*` IS a `Ifoo*`. The conversion is implicit. `dynamic_cast` is used when you don't know if the pointer you have is of another type and you want to check at run time by checking if the `dynamic_cast` returns `NULL`.

Also, if `function` is not intended to reassign the pointer you've passed in, it's not necessary to pass in as *&. Just pass *.

Comment: The implicit conversion also creates a temporary, and cannot bind to the argument.

Answer (score 0):

You function signature `bool function(Ifoo *&ref);` asks for a pointer to a *reference*. This is not the same as `bool function(Ifoo* ref);` which just asks for a normal pointer. Just use `Ifoo* ref` and it will work.